# In TFS 2015, what are the colored boxes next to the title?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

When viewing TFS work items online, what do the colored boxes next to the title indicate?  I don't see similar boxes when I view the project from within Visual Studio, only when looking at it in a browser.  Also I only see red and yellow; are there other colors as well?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors are work items types colors, each work item type have his color, and they only available in the Web UI and not in VS.

Usually, the red color is for Bug and Yellow color is for Task.

The colors are defined in the process config XML file, you can export the file (with `witadmin exportprocessconfig ...`) and change the colors to those you want, then import the file (`witadmin importprocessconfig ...`) back to TFS.

Example:

```
<workitemcolors>
  <workitemcolor name="Product Backlog Item" secondary="FFD6ECF2" primary="FF009CCC" />
  <workitemcolor name="Feature" secondary="FFEEE2F2" primary="FF773B93" />
  <workitemcolor name="Task" secondary="FFF6F5D2" primary="FFF2CB1D" />
  <workitemcolor name="Bug" secondary="FFFAEAE5" primary="FFCC293D" />
  <workitemcolor name="Code Review Request" secondary="FFFCEECF" primary="FFFF9D00" />
  <workitemcolor name="Code Review Response" secondary="FFFCEECF" primary="FFFF9D00" />
  <workitemcolor name="Feedback Request" secondary="FFFCEECF" primary="FFFF9D00" />
  <workitemcolor name="Feedback Response" secondary="FFFCEECF" primary="FFFF9D00" />
  <workitemcolor name="Impediment" secondary="FFFCEECF" primary="FFFF9D00" />
  <workitemcolor name="Shared Steps" secondary="FFFCEECF" primary="FFFF9D00" />
  <workitemcolor name="Test Case" secondary="FFFCEECF" primary="FFFF9D00" />
</workitemcolors>
```